# Hide menu list on mobile screen

Tags: css

To hide the menu bar on mobile screen i used:

```
@media (min-width:320px){
    menu{display:none;}
}

@media (min-width:481px){
    menu{display:none;} 
}
```

But this also lead to disable the menu on desktops too.
This is the website [whiskersjersey.co.uk](http://www.whiskersjersey.co.uk/)

Comment: `@media (max-width: ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@media (max-width:481px) {menu{display:none;}}` instead of `min-width`if you just want the menu bar to be hide on mobile screen

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
@media (max-width:481px){
    menu{display:none;}
}
```

instead of `min-width`. I would also recommend using selectors (`.menu` or `#menu`) instead of a direct DOM element targeting, since this element itself can be used in other parts of the website and this will give you a better accuracy on what you desire to style.

Comment: He's not using a selector, he's literally targeting the menu DOM element.

Comment: @ Alexander De Sousa no I saw him website he used class name menu in ul. check website

Comment: Yes he has used a ul.menu, however go up the tree and you will see a container that is the menu DOM element. So his CSS is actually valid since he wants to target that element, not the UL within.

Comment: @Dhaarani he is indeed targeting the `menu` element `<menu class="menu-nonr">`.